# execute tmux status-left with users bash-profile loaded

Tags: bash, tmux

I am attempting to update my tmux status with the currently running timer (if one is there). I'm using the [timetrap](https://github.com/samg/timetrap) ruby gem for this.  The issue (I think) I'm having is that the gem expects to be loaded in the context of a user.  So, If I set my status to just uptime (for example)

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=red,bg=default]#(uptime)'
```

That works just fine.

What I want to do is execute `t n` which returns the currently running timer if one is active when run from the command prompt. However, this fails.

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=red,bg=default]#(t n )'  # fails
```

Is there a way to execute the above in the context of my logged in self? Is this an incredibly bad practice?